# How to change order of elements inside tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yeu7B/)

I'm using this table with [css-trick](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) solution for responsive tables. Now what I would also like to do is to change the order of elements once the table gets changed (768px) so that `<h3>` and image change orders so it will be 1. title, 2. image, 3. text.

How can I do that?

here is what i have sofar

```
<table border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="aimg">
                <img src="#">
            </td>
            <td class="atext">

<h3>Title 1</h3>

                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="aimg">
                <img src="#">
            </td>
            <td class="atext">

<h3>Title2</h3>

                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

css

```
.actions table td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.actions table td.aimg {
    width:175px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
.actions table td.atext {
    padding-left:20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    .actions table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }
    .actions table tr {
        border-bottom:1px dashed #c0c7c7;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }
    .actions table td.aoptions {
        padding-left:0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will be difficult without reordering the way you've set up your html. Is that an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XTEY8/1/)**

That's a bit tricky because of the table markup.
Basically, you give the **tr** this css:

```
position: relative;
```

Then you position the title absolute to the top left and give the image the proper top padding, based on the height of the title.

There might be a better and more flexible solution for this.

Also... why are you using table markup for an element which is clearly no table?

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I was using tables because I couldn't align the title and text next to the images on right. Do you have a better solutions for this too ? :)

Comment: I have this right now, but it's not ideal either: http://jsfiddle.net/XTEY8/5/embedded/result/ I may look into it later, or you fix it.